# Logging User after Persist Rehydration

Tags: react-native, redux

I am trying to login user after Rehydration in react-native. I am not sure how to go about redirecting user after I have data in the store.

Here is how I setup my PersistGate in my index.js file:

```
class AppRedux extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate persistor={persistor} loading={<SplashScreen />}>
          <App />
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => AppRedux);
```

**SplashScreen.js**:

```
class SplashScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    props.navigation.navigate(RouteNames.Home);
  }
  render() {
    return <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "green" }}></View>;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    rehydrated: state.user.rehydrated
  };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SplashScreen);
```

The problem with this approach is that I am not able to navigate from splash screen. I get Navigation prop is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"loading" prop in "PersistGate" is just a dummy component to show loader until Persist Rehydration .  "App"(navigation component) will load after Rehydration where you can receive "navigation" prop and can access store.**

Try this like described in official site [Auth Flow](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html)

Create AuthLoading Screen and set navigation from there

**App.js**

```
const AppStack = createStackNavigator({ Home: HomeScreen, Other: OtherScreen });
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({ SignIn: SignInScreen });

export default createAppContainer(
  createSwitchNavigator(
    {
      AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
      App: AppStack,
      Auth: AuthStack,
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
    }
  )
);
```